# Django: CheckConstraint return 500 when conditions are wrong

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I tried to use "models.CheckConstraint" to validate birthday field like that:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True)

    class Meta:
       constraints = [
          models.CheckConstraint(
             check=Q(birthday__lt=date.today()),
             name='check_birthday')
       ]
```

When "birthday" < date.today(), it's work fine but when I type some value of "birthday" > date.today(), it shows me an error:

```
IntegrityError at /api/user/
CHECK constraint failed: check_birthday

Request Method: POST
Django Version: 3.0.7
Python Version: 3.7.3
```

I followed the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#constraints

Please tell me why? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntegrityError is an error thrown by database handler, not by view, serializer, form or whatever. Therefore your view does not know what to do with it and passes it as server error.

Comment: I'm using SQLite. Do you think I should switch to using MySQL?

Comment: It really depends. If you want to play around and not worry about efficiency, stay with SQLite. If it's a hobby project, but you want to learn from it, go for a mature database like MySQL, PostgreSQL. If you want your project to be run in production, you definitely MUST use MySQL, PostgreSQL or similar solution.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your suggestion ^^

Comment: Glad I could help :). If this solves your issue, please mark this answer so that others know that this question has been answered.